# PHP adodb dump from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, dump, adodb

I've got a PHP development environment using PostgreSQL and a hosting environment using MySQL.  I'm using adodb as an abstraction layer for easy migration between the two.

I'd like to dump the MySQL table(s) and restore them in PGSQL, and vice versa.  In PGSQL I would use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` to accomplish this, but that won't be applicable for a MySQL table.

Does adodb offer some command to dump or backup a table in a different format?  Like

```
$dbConnection -> Dump('mytable','pgsqlFormat');
```

or something?

If not, any suggestions are of course welcomed.  Thanks in advance.

---

Will end up exporting and importing CSV files to solve this problem.

A note to future adodb users who stumble across this question:

I thought when I started that AdoDB was the only option for a database abstraction layer.
Turns out the PDO extension in PHP does the same thing (and more), natively, and with better support.

I've switched to PDO now.  Didn't know there was a (better IMO) option to adodb :)  Hope that saves someone some time.

Comment: As much as I prefer PostgreSQL over MySQL: using a different DBMS for development and testing than in production is a bad idea. I would suggest you use MySQL for development as well (or search for a PostgreSQL hoster)

Comment: Thanks horse, I'll keep that in mind (and maybe implement also).  But in the spirit of "can it be done" I shall optimistically bumble forward.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use MySQL's mysqldump command and then import into PostgreSQL with psql -f?

Comment: `psql` is PervasiveSQL, not sure that's what you meant?

Comment: psql is the PostgreSQL command line tool. http://www.postgresonline.com/downloads/special_feature/postgresql83_psql_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: oh ok.  will be getting back to this problem in a few days, in the meantime thanks for your help.

Comment: Will actually end up dumping CSVs, if I do it at all.  Strongly recommended over dumps, "they" say.